# Javascript function binding issue

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

before three years I was a javascript guru. After the JQuery release I forgot everything about JavaScript. This may be a great drawback of this framework, for me. LOL

My issue How I bind a function with the onload event of the document? 
I tried so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    d.onload=function(){
        alert('Welcome');
    }
</script>
```

also I tried `document.onload = function()` etc etc but none works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

```
window.onload
```

actually.  You don't use the `onload` property of the `body` element, nor of the `document` object.

In action:

http://jsfiddle.net/5CP7Z/

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.onload function. Some code to explain

```
function load() {  
    alert("load event detected!");  
  }  
  window.onload = load;
```